# How do I import 2 different files icons?

Tags: html, css, web, icons

I would to know how to import a new pack of icons and place in the same css file. I have 2 icon files....flaticon.woff and new.woff and I don't know how to call the new.woff's file without generating error.
How I call the file icon?

```
@font-face {  
    font-family: "Flaticon";  
    url("./Flaticon.woff") format("woff"), src: url("./new.woff") format("woff"),  font-weight: normal; 
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I put this but the css file only calls the new's file.

and....

```
.icon-buildings:before { content: "\f100"; }//new.woff file
.icon-add_disabled:before{content: "\f100";color: #d4d4d4;}// overwrites this(flaticons)
```

Comment: Don't think you can set multiple woffs to the same font family, so "import" the two fonts in separate @font-faces. Note though that both fonts can't use the same family name either as the latter will overwrite the first.

Comment: and how i change the "id"? or place in seperate @font-face it will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two @font-faces, one for each font.

```
@font-face {  
    font-family: "Flaticon";  
    src: url("./Flaticon.woff") format("woff");
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {  
    font-family: "New";  
    src: url("./new.woff") format("woff");
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Then assign the font when needed, e.g

```
.icon-buildings:before {
    font-family: "New";
    content: "\f100";
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Now it works... i dont assign the new font-family to this: [class^="icon-"]:before, [class*=" icon-"]:before,[class^="icon-"]:after, [class*=" icon-"]:after